# How to put an Excel file in a home directory so an R project can be opened on different computers?

Tags: r, excel

I am using XLConnect to load an excel document and I want the R file to be able to be opened and run on other computers. Because when I use `file.path()` to load the Excel document from my local computer, if I share the document with someone else, their file path will be different it won't work.

So I am wondering if there is a way to send the R project to someone but still have it be able to load.

Comment: The standard way to do this is to have a single working directory which contains your script and data. This way the file.path should only be the file name.

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it is to package the script, then have the Excel/csv file in the inst folder in the package. The file path is then something like:

```
file <- read.csv(file = system.file("filename.csv", package = "packageName"), sep = "|", 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Obviously it is a bit different if it is an Excel file, but then you would just use your Excel-reading function instead of read.csv.